# How to apply a serie of patches with git

Tags: git

It is convenient to send sets of patches using `git send-email`. But once I received a set of patch, how to apply them? Especially, how to apply them in right order?

If I save them in a separate Maildir and I give this Maildir in argument to `git am`, patches are not applied in right order.

Currently, I specify each file separately on `git am` command line, but it's tedious.

Comment: `git am` applies maildir entries in sorted order, but the sort is a very simple one in which "12" comes after "1" but before "2": 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 3, 4...  Short of fixing `git am` internally the standard trick is to make sure "short" names have leading 0s, so that the sort is 01, 02, 03, ..., 10, 11, 12, ...  Or, you can put all single-digit patches in one dir, 2-digit patches in another.

Comment: @torek: Strange. On my system, when I use `format-patch`, all patches have a four-digit prefix with leading zeros to avoid this problem. Is `send-email` different from that?

Comment: @krlmlr: Yes, that's why most people don't run into a problem. There's some email systems that save by some other technique or something (I'm not sure where the problem starts, only what happens afterward :-) ).

Comment: @torek: Names of files in Maildir are not related with theirs subjects (nor to patch number).

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions would be:

```
git am $(perl -e  'my @r = sort { `grep Subject: $a` cmp `grep Subject: $b` } @ARGV; print "@r"' Maildir/new/*)
```

I strongly dislikes this hack. Is anyone has a better idea?